# How to show an infinite series diverges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ converge, formal multiplication would suggest that

$\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \right)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty c_k$, such that   $c_k=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} a_j b_{k-j}$

How can I show that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty c_k$ doesn't converge if $a_k=b_k=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\sqrt{k}}$ for $k\ge 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note by AM-GM inequality, when $k$ is even,
$$c_k = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} a_j b_{k-j} = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt j}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k-j}} \ge 2 \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{2(k-1)}{k} \to 2.$$

Thus $\{c_k\}$ does not go to zero and so $\sum c_k$ diverges.

Comment: Is there a way to show it just using the fact that the $c_k$ terms don't appoach 0?

Comment: I think you want to write $|c_k| = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}|a_jb_{k-j}|.$

Comment: @Burgundy I think that's what he's doing.

Comment: @zhw : Thanks. The answer is edited.